# Pass data from child controller to PageViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `PageViewcontroller` has 3 child controllers. I want to pass data from first child to Root `PageViewController`
This is my Root Controller.

I tried :

```
class RootViewController: UIPageViewController ,UIPageViewControllerDataSource{

var isSelectAnything : Bool = false


func addRightBottom(sendBool : Bool){
    self.isSelectAnything = sendBool
    print(isSelectAnything) // always return false even I select a cell from my child



}
```

This is my Child Controller.

```
class FirstView: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

//There is a collectionview and this method works on :

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let sendData = RootViewController()
        sendData.addRightBottom(sendBool: true)



}
```

When I select a cell from collectionview I want to change `isSelectAnything` value with true but its always return false.I searched but cant find any solutions.

I tried protocols but Its didnt work again

Comment: The problem is `let sendData = RootViewController()`. That is a _different_ RootViewController. See http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let sendData = RootViewController()
```

To

```
let sendData = parent as! RootViewController
```

Comment: I encounter this issues first. Thank to answer. It works